# Execute if statement only once when conditional is met

Tags: javascript, if-statement, boolean, conditional-statements

I have a function like so:

```
function foundGold(ptX, ptY) {
  var gridX = Math.floor(ptX / 36);
  var gridY = Math.floor(ptY / 36);
  if(mapArray[gridY][gridX] == 3) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

`if(foundGold(boatPosX + 36, boatPosY)) {
    goldAmount+= 1;
    gold.innerHTML = goldAmount;
  }`

It check my game character position and if it steps on the certain part of the array, than means that the condition is true and the function keeps running. So in this case I check in another function if `foundGold` is true and if it is, give user some gold. The problem is that while the condition is true, the player will keep getting endless amount of gold, unless he steps off from that position and and condition is no longer true.

Now how can I make this so that even if user keeps standing in one spot and the condition is true for the whole time, he won't keep getting gold and the function will execute only once, no matter for how long the condition is true?

I don't want to keep adding `+=1` to `goldAmount` all the time while the condition is true, only once. Is it possible to exit it after one run or anything like that?

Comment: *"endless amounts of gold"* ... Sign me up on that program!

Comment: Personally I'd make an array that stores not only gold locations, but also whether that location has been 'mined' or not. When the player attempts to mine there, simply check if it has been mined already or not. If not, mine it, and set the flag.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I call it inside my if statement as you can see. And the if statement is inside a main/game loop which is running all the time using rAf

Comment: Why not just remove the gold from the array?.  eg.  `mapArray[gridY][gridX] = 0` or similar..

Comment: @ObsidianAge the array is only for the map/world of the game, not anything else, so I can't store anything else in there. Want to keep it clean. I don't know about flags in programming but I will read some more about it and will try to implement it in my code the other way.

Comment: @Keith that works great as well, simple quick solution. Of course if I would like to keep it there for other players too, that would not work, but for now it's fine I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to modify your original array, you can store the information elsewhere. If it's only used in the one function, I'd just store it on the function itself. Since you're using primitives, you can easily flatten it to a single key, combined with the playerId:

```
function foundGold( ptX, ptY, playerId ) {

    const gridX = Math.floor( ptX / 36 );
    const gridY = Math.floor( ptY / 36 );

    if ( mapArray[ gridY ][ gridX ] === 3 ) {

        // Gold exists; check if player already found it
        const key = `_memory;${playerId};${gridX};${gridY}`;
        if ( this[ key ] ) return false;
        this[ key ] = true;

        return true;

    }

    return false;

}
```

Alternatively, you can have a 3-dimensional array.